# How to link file name to its data when plotting in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, loops, plot, matlab-figure

I have data in text files.

/season#_teamName.txt %many seasons for many teams

Each text file has 2 columns:

1 - game day number (1 to 30)

2 - position of the team at this particular game day.

I'd like to see how a position at the end of each season (day 30) changes for a certain team. 
In this case Y axis would show position, X axis season number (inreasing).

I'm using the code below, but I'm not connecting season number with the position. My question is how I can do that.

```
files=dir('result/*teamName.txt'); %read files only for a certain team, text files are located in 'result' folder.

for k = 1:length(files), 

FileName=strcat('result/',files(k).name); 
TempData=dlmread(FileName);
x=TempData(:,1); % read column 1 for gameday #
y=TempData(:,2); % read column 2 for position
```

Then, I want to plot y(30) for each season, where y(30) would give me position 
at the last game day.

```
plot(k,y(30)); % 

end
```

My mistake here is that I'm not linking position number to a season number from 
the file name.

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's happening here is that your `x` and `y` variables are constantly being mutated and you're not saving the values per file.  Also, you probably want to read the season number for a particular team.  What you'll need to do is for each filename that you have, you'll have to pull the number from the filename itself.  We can do that easily by placing all of your files into a cell array of strings, and then we can use regular expressions to pull out the numbers.

If your filenames are going to look the way you mentioned in your post (`season#_teamname.txt`), you simply have to look for the first occurrence of a string of numbers, then convert these into actual numbers as these were strings to begin with.

Do this first:

```
files=dir('result/*teamName.txt');
f = {files.name};
```

`f` will contain a cell array of filenames from the `dir` call.  Then when you're done, do this to extract out the actual numbers themselves:

```
seasons = cellfun(@str2double, regexp(f, '\d+', 'once', 'match'));
```

`seasons` will contain an array of season numbers.  Now all you have to do is iterate through each file, get your gameday and position numbers and store them into two big matrices - one for the gamedays and one for the position numbers.  Once you do that, it'll be easy to slice through the position numbers and pick out a day over all seasons.

From your files, it only looks like there are 30 gamedays and so we should expect 2 columns of 30 values each.  Therefore, let's create a two 2D matrices where each column is one season for the gamedays (`x`) and the positions (`y`) and we can slice through the `y` matrix to get what we need when we're done.

Something like this:

```
x = zeros(30, numel(files));
y = zeros(30, numel(files));

for k = 1:numel(files)
    FileName=strcat('result/',files(k).name); 
    TempData=dlmread(FileName);
    season = seasons(k);
    x(:,season) = TempData(:,1); 
    y(:,season) = TempData(:,2);
end
```

Now that you're done, we can plot the season number (horizontal) and the position of the 30th day (vertical) over all seasons.

```
plot(seasons, y(30,:));
```

The last row (row 30) should be the positions over all seasons as each season is one column.

## Minor Note

If your first column is only going to be from 1 to 30 for every single file, then it's pretty superfluous to get the gameday numbers.  All you really need are the positions (second columns)... but I've put the gameday numbers in any way because I'm not sure what your ultimate application is going to be, so it may be nice to have those somewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the response! I'm trying to understand the idea. What is     season = out(k); what 'out' stands for?

Comment: @user40 - typo from a previous iteration.  I had `seasons` as `out` originally, but I changed the variable and forgot to change it in the main `for` loop I wrote.  Let me change.  That should be `season = seasons(k);`.  Try it now!

Comment: I tried it as it is, just using your code, and got this http://joxi.ru/KAxePz3SD8KYr8  then I switched axises plot(y(30,:),seasons); and got this http://joxi.ru/zAN0RDbfnZj0m9 The thing is there are way more than 20 seasons, but I always get 19 as maximum value for x. Also, I'd like to have season number on the x axis. I'll double check if I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: Out of all of the answers I've written, this probably holds the record for the latest accepted answer I've seen lol.... 3 years later.  Better late than never. Thanks.

Comment: well it took me 3 years to understand what the hell you wrote. just kidding lol i decided to go through all my questions and choose an answer)

Comment: @user40 lmao. I appreciate your sense of humour.  Cheers mate.